# Sharing Audio and Text With Single Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-debug, android-sharing

Hi It would help me greatly If anyone could please help me out. I have been trying to find a solution to Share my Audio File with a Text using Intent. I am just trying to share it on Whatsapp alone. It would be greatly appreciated if any of you could spare time out to help me out of this problem. When I run my code only the sound is shared. No text. 
This is my code:

```
   public void buttonClick(View v) {
    try {

        String a = copyFiletoExternalStorage(R.raw.accio, "accio.mp3");

        String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";


        Intent shareMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //set WhatsApp application.
        shareMedia.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        shareMedia.setType("*/*");
        //set path of media file in ExternalStorage.
        shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(a));
        shareMedia.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        shareMedia.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareMedia, "Compartiendo archivo."));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatsapp no se encuentra instalado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I want the user to share the sound and the text in just one intent.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to add provider_paths.xml

[see this video to add file provider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKByKkrv_5Y)

my file provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

then add this line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
         <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
   </provider>
```

then use this code to share your voice and text

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text ... ");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        if (hasReadExternalStoragePermission()) {
          Uri uriImage = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "voice.wav"));
          sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriImage);
          sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
        }
        sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "share"));
```

I hope it has been helpful

Comment: Please consider adding some detail explaining how does it solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` instead of `Intent.ACTION_SEND`

```
    Intent shareMedia = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    //set WhatsApp application.
    shareMedia.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    shareMedia.setType("*/*");

    String[] extraMimeTypes = {"audio/*", "image/*"};
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, extraMimeTypes);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

    shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(a));
    shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
    shareMedia.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareMedia, "Compartiendo archivo."));
```

Comment: No Buddy, Still no change!

Comment: No dude... only sound is coming... I changed your code to match with mine... but still text did not come with Sound!!